# Significantly higher testing accuracy on mnist with keras than tensorflow.keras

Tags: tensorflow, testing, optimization, keras, mnist

I was verifying with a basic example my TensorFlow (v2.2.0), Cuda (10.1), and cudnn (libcudnn7-dev_7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.1_amd64.deb) and I'm getting weird results...

When running the following example in Keras as shown in https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/ I get the ~99% acc @validation. When I adapt the imports run via the TensorFlow I get only 86%.

I might be forgetting something.

To run using tensorflow:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Sadly, I get the following output:

```
Epoch 2/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 2.2245 - accuracy: 0.2633 - val_loss: 2.1755 - val_accuracy: 0.4447
Epoch 3/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 2.1485 - accuracy: 0.3533 - val_loss: 2.0787 - val_accuracy: 0.5147
Epoch 4/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 2.0489 - accuracy: 0.4214 - val_loss: 1.9538 - val_accuracy: 0.6021
Epoch 5/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.9224 - accuracy: 0.4845 - val_loss: 1.7981 - val_accuracy: 0.6611
Epoch 6/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.7748 - accuracy: 0.5376 - val_loss: 1.6182 - val_accuracy: 0.7039
Epoch 7/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.6184 - accuracy: 0.5750 - val_loss: 1.4296 - val_accuracy: 0.7475
Epoch 8/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 1.4612 - accuracy: 0.6107 - val_loss: 1.2484 - val_accuracy: 0.7719
Epoch 9/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.3204 - accuracy: 0.6402 - val_loss: 1.0895 - val_accuracy: 0.7945
Epoch 10/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.2019 - accuracy: 0.6650 - val_loss: 0.9586 - val_accuracy: 0.8097
Epoch 11/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 1.1050 - accuracy: 0.6840 - val_loss: 0.8552 - val_accuracy: 0.8216
Epoch 12/12
469/469 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 1.0253 - accuracy: 0.7013 - val_loss: 0.7734 - val_accuracy: 0.8337
Test loss: 0.7734305262565613
Test accuracy: 0.8337000012397766
```

Nowhere near 99.25% as when I import Keras. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**Discrepancy in optimiser parameters between keras and tensorflow.keras**

So the crux of the issue lies in the different default parameters for the Adadelta optimisers in Keras and Tensorflow. Specifically, the different learning rates. We can see this with a simple check. Using the Keras version of the code, `print(keras.optimizers.Adadelta().get_config())` outpus

```
{'learning_rate': 1.0, 'rho': 0.95, 'decay': 0.0, 'epsilon': 1e-07}
```

And in the Tensorflow version, `print(tf.optimizers.Adadelta().get_config()` gives us

```
{'name': 'Adadelta', 'learning_rate': 0.001, 'decay': 0.0, 'rho': 0.95, 'epsilon': 1e-07}
```

As we can see, there is a discrepancy between the learning rates for the Adadelta optimisers. Keras has a default learning rate of `1.0` while Tensorflow has a default learning rate of `0.001` (consistent with their other optimisers).

**Effects of a higher learning rate**

Since the Keras version of the Adadelta optimiser has a larger learning rate, it converges much faster and achieves a high accuracy within 12 epochs, while the Tensorflow Adadelta optimiser requires a longer training time. If you increased the number of training epochs, the Tensorflow model could potentially achieve a 99% accuracy as well.

**The fix**

But instead of increasing the training time, we can simply initialise the Tensorflow model to behave in a similar way to the Keras model by changing the learning rate of Adadelta to `1.0`. i.e.

```
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=1.0), # Note the new learning rate
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Making this change, we get the following performance running on Tensorflow:

```
Epoch 12/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 102s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0287 - accuracy: 0.9911 - val_loss: 0.0291 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Test loss: 0.029134796149221757
Test accuracy: 0.9907
```

which is close to the desired 99.25% accuracy.

p.s. Incidentally, it seems that the different default parameters between Keras and Tensorflow is a known issue that was fixed but then reverted:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/12841 software development is hard.